# Using AMPscript/SSJS to unsubscribe from a parent business unit on a CloudPage from a child business unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

If you click 'Unsubscribe from All' on the Subscriber in the Subscriber Properties modal in the parent business unit's context or when you perform an SSJS `subscriber.Unsubscribe();` on a CloudPage on the parent business unit the result is the subscriber is unsubscribed from all child business units too. I've attached a picture that should help:

[image]

Can you perform that same process on the Parent Business Unit if the CloudPage belongs to the Child Business Unit?

I've tried a couple of solutions and it doesn't seem possible

If you run the code below on a CloudPage that belongs to a Child Business Unit, it will perform a [Master Unsubscribe](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_master_unsubscribe.htm) the user from Child Business Unit that the CloudPage belongs to.

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

  var subscriberKey = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("skey");
  var subscriber = Subscriber.Init(subscriberKey);
  var status = subscriber.Unsubscribe();
</script>
```

I've also tried a suggestion from a [similar answer I received for a different question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/262583/68736):

```
<script runat="server">
  var subscriberKey = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("skey");
  var businessUnitId = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("clientId");
  var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
  prox.setClientId({ "ID": businessUnitId }); //Proxy impersonates the parent BU
  var props = [
    { Name: "SubscriberKey", Value: subscriberKey },
  ];
  var data = prox.execute(props, "LogUnsubEvent");
</script>
```

However, I received the below error, presumably because you cannot impersonate a parent business unit from a child business unit:

```
{
  "Status": "Error",
  "RequestID": "<<request-id>>",
  "Results": [
    {
      "StatusCode": "Error",
      "StatusMessage": "RequestID: <<request-id>> Message: MemberID 123456789 does not have access to ClientID: ID[012345678] PartnerClientKey[] UserID[] PartnerUserKey[] supplied in the request",
      "OrdinalID": 0,
      "Results": null,
      "ErrorCode": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Maybe there is a means of granting access?

Comment: you should be able to use the same logic from this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262436/using-ampscript-ssjs-how-do-you-unsubscribe-a-subscriber-from-a-child-business-u/262583#262583 and set the clientID to the parent BU.

Comment: I think the issue with that solution for this situation is that if the CloudPage is on a child business unit, you'll receive an error about not having access to the parent BU. An error like this:

`{
  "Status": "Error",
  "RequestID": "<<request-id>>",
  "Results": [
    {
      "StatusCode": "Error",
      "StatusMessage": "RequestID: <<request-id>> Message: MemberID 123456789 does not have access to ClientID: ID[012345678] PartnerClientKey[] UserID[] PartnerUserKey[] supplied in the request",
      "OrdinalID": 0,
      "Results": null,
      "ErrorCode": 0
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Check your permission sets on the child BU users. With the correct permission sets, you should be able to access the All Subs list from any BU user.  There is also a permission setting for each BU that you can have it set so if someone Master Unsubs (unsub from All Subscribers) on that BU they unsub at parent level (Global Unsub) instead of default behavior of at BU level only (Master Unsub). But this is a sweeping rule and will pertain to any and all Master Unsubs in the BU.

Comment: Here is the link to the answer with more info on the Global unsub BU permissions: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195186/how-do-you-unsubscribe-a-subscriber-at-business-unit-level

Answer (score 1):

Following script from Adam Spriggs works like a charm: 
https://sprignaturemoves.com/one-click-unsubscribe-with-ampscript/

```
%%[

var @debug
var @jid
var @listid
var @batchid
var @email
var @skey
var @reason
var @unsubscribeAll

set @debug = 0
set @jid = AttributeValue("jobid")
set @listid = AttributeValue("listid")
set @batchid = AttributeValue("_JobSubscriberBatchID")
set @email = AttributeValue("emailaddr")
set @skey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")
set @reason = "One-Click Unsubscribe"
set @unsubscribeAll = RequestParameter("ua")

/* if we know the subscriber */
if not empty(@skey) then

   var @lue
   var @lue_prop
   var @lue_statusCode
   var @overallStatus
   var @requestId
   var @Response
   var @Status
   var @Error

   /* if unsubscribing from all, then set the job, batch and listids to blank, effectively doing a global unsub */
   if @unsubscribeAll == "1" then
     set @jid = ""
     set @listid = ""
     set @batchid = ""
   endif

   /* create a request to inject an unsub event into the LogUnsubEvent platform table */
   set @lue = CreateObject("ExecuteRequest")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent")

   /*
    In order to invoke the request, we need to associate the following information with it to define the subscriber context and the job context:

    1. Subscriber Key
    2. JobId associated with the email send
    3. ListID the email was sent to
    4. BatchID the email was sent to
    5. Reason for the unsub
   */

   /* 1. define and associate Subscriber Key to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @skey)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* 2. define and associate JobID to the request */
   if not empty(@jid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "JobID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @jid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 3. define and associate ListID to the request */
   if not empty(@listid) then
     set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "ListID")
     SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @listid)
     AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 4. define and associate BatchID to the request */
   if not empty(@batchid) then
    set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID")
    SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @batchid)
    AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)
   endif

   /* 5. define and associate unsub reason to the request */
   set @lue_prop = CreateObject("APIProperty")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Name", "Reason")
   SetObjectProperty(@lue_prop, "Value", @reason)
   AddObjectArrayItem(@lue, "Parameters", @lue_prop)

   /* finally, you invoke the request */
   set @lue_statusCode = InvokeExecute(@lue, @overallStatus, @requestId)

   /* extract messages from the response */
   set @Response = Row(@lue_statusCode, 1)
   set @Status = Field(@Response,"StatusMessage")
   set @Error = Field(@Response,"ErrorCode")

endif

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>jid: ", @jid))
  output(concat("<br>listid: ", @listid))
  output(concat("<br>batchid: ", @batchid))
  output(concat("<br>email: ", @email))
  output(concat("<br>skey: ", @skey))
  output(concat("<br>reason: ", @reason))
  output(concat("<br>unsubscribeAll: ", @unsubscribeAll))
  output(concat("<br>overallStatus: ", @overallStatus))
  output(concat("<br>requestId: ", @requestId))
  output(concat("<br>Response: ", @Response))
  output(concat("<br>Status: ", @Status))
  output(concat("<br>Error: ", @Error))
endif

]%%
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this will log the event at the BU level, the OP wants it to go at the parent level regardless of where the call is made.

Comment: please see the comment: /* if unsubscribing from all, then set the job, batch and listids to blank, effectively doing a global unsub */ - I am using this myself and it works from any BU

Comment: Does it show it as unsubscribed at the enterprise level, or at the BU level? Removing job, batch, list, etc. will cause it to unsubscribe from all subscribers - which, depending on your permissions, can be either BU level or enterprise. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195186/how-do-you-unsubscribe-a-subscriber-at-business-unit-level

Comment: I believe he may have put the wrong terminology, it is not global, but Master unsub - which is, by default, BU level. "If the job context cannot be established because you did not supply any of these parameters or only supplied the BatchID, the UnsubEvent is not created. The subscriber is also Master Unsubscribed from the system instead of being unsubscribed from a particular list." - (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm)

Comment: If I used the wrong terminology I apologize, I'm still new to marketing cloud. I'll try to clarify. If you click 'Unsubscribe from All' on the Subscriber in the Subscriber Properties modal in the parent business unit's context or when you perform an SSJS `subscriber.Unsubscribe();` on a CloudPage on the parent business unit the result is the subscriber is unsubscribed from all child business units too. I was curious if that type on unsubscribe action was possible from code on a CloudPage that belongs to a child business unit. I will try to reword the original post for better clarity.

Comment: @RickLocke - the terminology error was not you, it was in the code provided by zmj.