# Is there an API to mark Business Unit level Subscriber Status in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there an API to mark Business Unit level Subscriber Status in SFMC Or any other method except Import Subscriber Status file at Business Unit Level. In the SOAP API, When I don't specify the ClientID, it Unsubscribes at the Top Parent BU. When I specify the Child BU ClientID, I get the Success and OK message but nothing happens. The contact remains Unsubscribed in the Child BU.

**SOAP Envelope Body**

```
    <s:Body
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <UpdateRequest 
        xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
            <Client>
                <ID>10112222</ID>
            </Client>
            <SubscriberKey>0990D00000QnnJ5QWW</SubscriberKey>
            <Lists>
                <ID>1277</ID>
                <Status>Active</Status>
                <Action>Update</Action>
            </Lists>
        </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
</s:Body>
```

**SOAP Response Body**

```
<soap:Body>
    <UpdateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Results>
            <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
            <StatusMessage>Updated Subscriber.</StatusMessage>
            <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
            <Object xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <Client>
                    <ID>10112222</ID>
                </Client>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ID>1826055555</ID>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <SubscriberKey>0990D00000QnnJ5QWW</SubscriberKey>
                <Lists>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ID>1277</ID>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <Status>Active</Status>
                    <Action>Update</Action>
                </Lists>
            </Object>
        </Results>
        <RequestID>c3f170fe-4314-47c5-ba2b-77b1a89b8412</RequestID>
        <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
    </UpdateResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Comment: yes, through impersonation of the BU via ClientID: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/262436/using-ampscript-ssjs-how-do-you-unsubscribe-a-subscriber-from-a-child-business-u

Comment: @JonasLamberty, that didn't actually resolve my issue. When I don't specify the ClientID, it Unsubscribes at the Top Parent BU. When I specify the Child BU ClientID, I get the Success and OK message but nothing happens. The contact remains Unsubscribed in the Child BU. Updated the question with my request and response.